# How to stop submissions of commonly used passwords

Tags: python

I am creating a program that checks for a password's strength. I want to block the ability for someone to type a commonly used password such as 'Password1'. I was also looking into password entropy and couldn't really figure out how to incorporate that into my code. I'm new with python and have been trying my best, so please forgive me. Maybe some of you have ideas on what I can do.

```
import re

def password():
    print ('Hello and welcome to Austin’s Password Checker!\n\nThe password must be between 6 and 12 characters\n\nConsider a capital, lowercase and number for best results!\n')

while True:
    password = input('Enter a password:')
    if 6 <= len(password) < 12:
        break
    print ('The password must be between 6 and 12 characters.\nConsider having a capital, lowercase and a number for best results!')

password_scores = {0:'Terrible', 1:'Weak', 2:'Medium', 3:'Strong'}
password_strength = dict.fromkeys(['up', 'down', 'num','spcl'], False)
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    password_strength['up'] = True
if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    password_strength['down'] = True
if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    password_strength['num'] = True
score = len([b for b in password_strength.values() if b])

print ('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])

password()
```

Comment: create a list: `disallowed=['password', 'letmein', ...]`, then check if the password is in the list: `if password in disallowed: ...`

Comment: @BryanOakley, for a realistically-sized list of common passwords, an O(n) algorithm (and, yes, `item in list` is O(n)) is much too expensive. A set or dictionary lookup -- being O(1) -- makes much more sense.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You are right, but unless there are gigabytes of data it probably won't matter. Since this is a security related problem, speed isn't particularly important. For a beginner, it might be better to keep things simple until they understand the concept.

Comment: @BryanOakley, takes much less than gigabytes for performance to matter. A reasonable password list to use for this kind of operation is going to be *at least* the top 100,000 or so; 100,000 string comparisons is perfectly capable of being a perceptible delay in and of itself, especially since the common case is where there's no match so you have to compare against every single one of them. (Granted, if it's sorted, you can bisect a list very quickly too, but that's, again, more complex code than `if x in y`).

Comment: @BryanOakley, ...which is to say: Understanding algorithmic complexity is an *essential* thing for beginners -- people escape out into the wild without it and then they write atrocities like early versions of Puppet (which used to have a worst-case O(n^3) topological sort algorithm -- making it, at that point in the long-distant past, utterly unusable with sufficiently large dependency graphs).

Answer (score 3):

You can dump the passwords into a set (for quick lookups) and use one of the many online available dictionaries for actually frequently used passwords. (Most of them come from leaks, so it should be pretty much valid)
https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords

```
passwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('mostUsedPasswords.txt'))

if "matrix" in passwords:
    print("This password is frequently used")
```